# Retrieving the backcolor in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I'm a absolute beginner. Just started to play with C#. 
I want to switch the backcolor of a textBox.
If it is red, I want to change it into yellow.

Why is `if (textBox1.backcolor = Color.Red)` giving an error ?

Comment: Because the comparison operator is `==` . The error meassage should have given you a good hint, as it usually does.

Comment: `=` means assignment, `==` means compare

Answer (score 1):

using '=' is for assigning a value, use '==' to check if two things are equal

```
if (textBox1.backcolor == Color.Red)
{
    ...
}
```

What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

`(textBox1.backcolor = Color.Red)` is trying to set textBox1.backcolor to Color.Red.

What you want is `(textBox1.backcolor == Color.Red)` because that is the conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but
OK I used == but still an error Error CS1061 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'backcolor' and no extension method 'backcolor' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

If statements check booleans, you are using the wrong operator.

```
if (textBox1.backcolor == Color.Red)
{
    textBox1.backcolor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `==` , `=` is for assignment. And not backColor ,correct syntax is `BackColor`.

```
if (textBox1.BackColor == Color.Red)
    textBox1.BackColor  = Color.Yellow;
```